# How to nullify a css property so it's effectively deleted

Tags: css

I have many different css files. To acess them all and find specific css will be quite hard. Is there a way of cancelling out the following css, from various parts of the site, so that it's effectively deleted, using css? Everything in grey I want as though it doesn't exist along with the rule is stipulates obviously.

```
.awpcp-listing-excerpt {

 { /* float: left; */
  /* flex-grow: 2; */
 }

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
/* height: 50%; */
}



.awpcp-listing-excerpt-small .awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
thumbnail, .awpcp-listing-excerpt-medium .awpcp-listing- 
excerpt-thumbnail {
/* float: left; */
}

.displayaditemseven {
 /* width: 100%; */
 }

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-medium .awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
thumbnail {
 /* width: auto; */
}

.displayaditemsodd {
/* width: 100%; */
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
/* height: 0px; */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `unset` attribute on CSS for each class code and also add `!important` as to make sure it'll be done.

Example :

```
.awpcp-listing-excerpt {
    float: unset !important;
    flex-grow: unset !important;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
    height: unset !important;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-small .awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail, .awpcp-listing-excerpt-medium .awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail {
    float: unset !important;
}

.displayaditemseven {
    width: unset !important;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-medium .awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
thumbnail {
    width: unset !important;
}

.displayaditemsodd {
    width: unset !important;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
    height: unset !important;
}
```

You can also use jQuery for that :

```
<div class="element">source</div>   
    <div class="destination">destination</div>
      <script>
        $(".element").removeClass();
      </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE THAT** : If no parameter is specified, this method will remove ALL class names from the selected elements.

Comment: Thanks. I'll assume you're right and mark as correct.